# How to run pylint on hg commit?

Tags: mercurial, pylint

How to run pylint on hg commit ?

I've seen https://github.com/sebdah/git-pylint-commit-hook but I've also seen comments that I should be using a "Continuous Build System". In the context of a small side project I'm not sure what that means ? I'm assuming Jenkins, etc but that seems way over the top ? I would use git-pylint-commit-hook but I'm getting errors from when it tries to popen pylint and it all feels like a lot of pain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I've worked this out.

Setup [Paver](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Paver/) so it does the commit and before doing the actual commit will run pylint and stop the commit if the results from pylint aren't what they should be.

Comment: do you have a example of it?

Comment: Sorry I don't . I have looked but I can't find the project on which I was using this. I stopped using mercurial some time ago and so that issue isn't something I've had to think about in recent times.